# Ошибка при получении ответа. метод photos.search() VKApi Android

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Добрый день) Пишу приложение работающее с google map api  и vk api. При обращении к методу photos.search() должен возвращаеться объект, состоящий из количества найденных фото,и массива обектов VKApiPhoto. При одном запуске - возвращается ответ как и должен быть, но вот при следующем запуске - на любой запрос возвращается объект с пустым массивом VKPhotoApi. Отчего так?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
    ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private VKService vkService;
private PermissionService permissionService = new PermissionService();
private Marker marker;
private String accesToken;
private ArrayList<VKApiPhoto> listFoto;

private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_layout);
    mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    vkService = new VKService();
    VKSdk.login(this, vkService.scope);

    MapFragment mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
            accesToken = res.accessToken;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })) super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    permissionService.enableMyLocation(googleMap, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, this);
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }
    if (permissionService.isPermissionGranted(permissions, grantResults,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        permissionService.enableMyLocation(googleMap, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, this);
    } else {
        // Display the missing permission error dialog when the fragments resume.
        //mPermissionDenied = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    if (marker != null) {
        marker.remove();
    }
    marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Selected GEO"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    final VKRequest vKRequest = new VKRequest("photos.search", VKParameters.from(
            VKApiConst.LAT, latLng.latitude, VKApiConst.LONG, latLng.longitude,
            "start_time", 1392005288, "end_time", 1479658261, "count", 200, "radius", 10000,
             VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, accesToken));
    vKRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            try {
                JSONArray photosArray = response.json.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("items");
                for (int i = 0; i < photosArray.length(); i++) {
                    VKApiPhoto photo = new VKApiPhoto(photosArray.getJSONObject(i));
                    listFoto.add(photo);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: решилось, передачей в качестве параметра VKPhotoArray.class в VKRequest         `VKRequest vKRequest = new VKRequest("photos.search", VKParameters.from(
                VKApiConst.LAT, latLng.latitude, VKApiConst.LONG, latLng.longitude,
                "start_time", 1392005288, "end_time", 1479658261, "count", 200, "radius", 10000,
                 VKApiConst.ACCESS_TOKEN, accesToken, VKPhotoArray.class));`

Comment: не знаю, насколько это правильно... буду очень благодарен тому, кто объяснит. в документации объяснения не нашел